# Move shapefile from one folder to another using python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm working with shapefiles and using the ArcPy library. My script is creating a new shapefile based on a join and I want to know how to move the newly joined-shapefile from the environment location to a new folder. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: Call the Copy geo-processing tool to copy datasets.

Comment: You could use basic file copy operation, or you could use Copy Featureclass GP tool, the output will be the same. The later operation will be slower and involve more overhead.

Comment: To add to what Hornbydd and Dev have already said: 1.arcpy.Copy_management("originalSHP","pathandnameofdestintionSHP") 2.arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("originalSHP","pathtonewlocation", "NewName")

Comment: I'd use the arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion tool because that will copy all files for you instead of having to use a wildcard to copy all the other files associated with the .shp file using the python "copyfile" operation.

Comment: What are you using to perform your join?  [**Join Field**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000065000000) or [**Add Join**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000)?  In any event can you post a short block of your code to illustrate what you are doing?

Comment: arcpy.CopyFeatures_management()